# Call VBScript from Windows Explorer Context Menu

Tags: vbscript

I would like to open a certain file type (DocuWorks aka *.xdw) from Windows Explorer using VBScript. Apparently I can edit the Registry to associate a file type and pass the filename as a parameter (%1?) to the script.

The reason I want to do this is because some files on our shared drive are so deep within layers of subfolders that the program cannot open them and I've been requested to come up with something to help users get around the problem. My solution is to create a unique folder within Documents, then copy the file there, open it, then delete the folder.

Here's some code I wrote, but I was getting the filename from within a HTA file that uses a file input type. If I can get the filename via a parameter, I'll edit the code to suit, but at this stage, I do not know how to do it.

```
Option Explicit

Const dblHeight = 130
Const dblWidth = 700

Private sTempFolder
Private oFileScriptingObject

'Launches when the HTA file is opened.
Sub window_onLoad()
    Dim oWScript
    Dim iRandom
    
    'Set the HTA form location and size
    With Self
        
        .MoveTo Window.screen.Height / 2 - (dblHeight / 2), Window.screen.Width / 2 - (dblWidth / 2)
        
        .ResizeTo dblWidth, dblHeight
        
    End With

    'Use Wscript.Shell, create the unique folder path and name        
    Set oWScript = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    
    sTempFolder = oWScript.SpecialFolders("mydocuments") & "\" & "Temp"
    
    For iRandom = 1 To 10
        
        Randomize
        
        sTempFolder = sTempFolder & Int((10 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
        
    Next
    
    'Use FileSystemObject to create the folder
    Set oFileScriptingObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    oFileScriptingObject.CreateFolder (sTempFolder)
    
    Set oWScript = Nothing
    
    Set oFileScriptingObject = Nothing
    
End Sub

'There's an Open button on the HTA form to call this
Sub OpenFile()
    Dim sTitle
    Dim sFilePath
    Dim sFileName
    Dim oShell
    
    sTitle = "Open DocuWorks File"

    'Get the file path from the file input on the form
    sFilePath = document.getElementById("file").Value
    
    If sFilePath = vbNullString Then
        
        MsgBox "Please use the Browse button to select a file", vbCritical, sTitle
        
        Exit Sub
        
    End If

    'Use Scripting.FileSystemObject to get the file name from the path
    'then copy the file to the unique folder. Also check the file extension (see note)
    'Note: Should have been to set the file input to filter and show DocuWorks files only
    'but for some reason "accept" attribute didn't work, maybe a HTA thing?
    Set oFileScriptingObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    With oFileScriptingObject
        
        sFileName = .GetFileName(sFilePath)
        
        If .GetExtensionName(sFileName) = "xdw" Then
            
            .CopyFile sFilePath, sTempFolder & "\"
            
            Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
            
            oShell.Open sTempFolder & "\" & sFileName
            
        Else
            
            MsgBox "Please select a DocuWorks file.（.xdw）", vbCritical, sTitle
            
        End If
        
    End With
    
    Set oFileScriptingObject = Nothing
    
    Set oShell = Nothing
    
End Sub

'Delete the folder and cleanup
Sub window_onBeforeUnLoad()
    
    Set oFileScriptingObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    oFileScriptingObject.DeleteFolder sTempFolder
    
    Set oFileScriptingObject = Nothing
    
End Sub

'There's a Close button on the HTA form to call this
Sub CloseMe()
    
    Self.Close()
    
End Sub
```

If I'm able to associate the file type within the Registry, I won't need to check the extension. But I really need help to make get this up and running from the Windows Explorer context menu.

Comment: Does this help: [Running a batch script by right clicking any file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852833/running-a-batch-script-by-right-clicking-any-file) ? its for a batch file, but should work for a vbs too

Comment: Possibly. How do I pass the file's path to my sFilePath variable in the OpenFile sub?

Comment: From a comment on the accepted answer:  `the filename is passed by Explorer as the first parameter to the invoked .bat`

Comment: Okay, I can use WScript.Arguments(0). Cool, thanks. At the moment, I have my script file on Desktop, and I am activating it by drag and dropping the file I want to open from Explorer. A new problem is that the code tries to delete the folder before the file is opened. How can I make the code delete the folder only after the file has opened?

Comment: WScript.Arguments(0) is shortening the file path to 55 characters. So that's another problem.

Comment: Figured out how to loop through WScript.Arguments! There is a limit to the length of the file path that can be used (I'm guessing 255?) , but I guess that cannot be helped.